# Display a number with culture info but without formatting

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, string.format

I thought this was simple; the .Net Framework has so many functions for formatting a number exactly as you want, but still, I haven't been able to make this work.

The problem: display a number according to the European rules, so with "." for a thousands separator and "," for a decimal separator, but without also fixing the number of decimals.

So, for example, if I have 1234, that is supposed to print as `"1.234"`, and 1234.5 is supposed to print as `"1.234,5"`. But none of the formats I've tried do exactly that!

Examples: suppose that `ci` is a CultureInfo with the correct settings, then

`num.ToString(ci)      -> "1234,5"`    decimals OK, but no thousands separator
`num.ToString("G", ci) -> "1234,5"`    same as above
`num.ToString("N", ci) -> "1.234,50"`  thousands separator OK, but too many decimals

and so on. Similar with using a `NumberFormatInfo` instead of a `CultureInfo`, or trying `String.Format` or `Convert.ToString`. Anybody have any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hardcode format string like this

```
num.ToString("###,###,###.####");
```

this will output with respect tu Current thread culture info. If you have european culture you will get "." as thousands separator. And this will output up to 4 decimals that are not equal 0. You can increase number of decimals  and number of groups if you have larger numbers or need greater precison.
But, not sure if there is a more elegant way...

Comment: Thank you! I tested a bit with this and it's definitely what I need. Except that with all #s, it displays nothing for the number 0, but you can replace the last # before the decimal point with a 0 without loss of functionality. So, this is it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you looking for this:

```
number.ToString("#,##0.##", customCulture);
```

Example of use:

```
double first = 12345.67;
double second = 1234567;
var customCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
customCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
Console.WriteLine("First :    " + first.ToString("#,##0.##", customCulture));
Console.WriteLine("Second: "   + second.ToString("#,##0.##", customCulture));
```

without define exact culture info you can not guarantee the same result in any culture.

This is result I get in console:

```
First :    12.345,67
Second: 1.234.567
```